# send entity for controller not working, php laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

in blade template

```
<form action="{{ route('leads.courses.restore', $lead->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <button type="submit">
    Restore 
  </button>
</form>
```

in routes

```
Route::post('leads/courses/{lead}/restore', 'LeadsCoursesController@restore')->name('leads.courses.restore');
```

in controller

```
public function restore(Lead $lead)
  {
    dd("ok");
  }
```

but i receive HTTP code 404, if i remove the parameter in controller receive "ok".

Comment: change ```public function restore(Lead $lead)``` to ```public function restore($lead)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens because you try to find a `soft deleted` record so to fix it add to your route `withTrashed()` to be like this

```php
Route::post('leads/courses/{lead}/restore', 'LeadsCoursesController@restore')
   ->withTrashed()
   ->name('leads.courses.restore');
```

for more info check this part in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#implicit-soft-deleted-models)

Comment: yea! I realized that, I had just made an answer, thanks for helping.

Comment: What a pity that using this function in routes is a functionality of laravel 9, in this system I'm using 7, I'll have to turn around in control lol.

Comment: in this case you need to pass your `id` to the controller like this `$lead` instead of this `Lead $lead`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
{{ route('leads.courses.restore', $lead->id) }}
```

Should be:

```
{{ route('leads.courses.restore', ['lead' => $lead->id]) }}
```

Or in Laravel 8+

```
 {{ route('leads.courses.restore', ['lead' => $lead]) }}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me!

Comment: This would change nothing. passing it in array form as above doesn't matter because it's just one parameter as defined in his route.

Comment: @Innovin you sure? :D

Comment: @AlexeyKhachatryan Absolutely. I use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was happening, as the name of the function suggests, I intended to restore a deleted lead and with that I was passing the id of a deleted lead as a parameter resulting in null when instantiating.
To solve, I sent the id and found the record using the Laravel function below.

```
public function restore(string $leadId)
    {
        $lead = Lead::withTrashed()->find($leadId);
        dd($lead);
    }
```